# Is it considered bad practice to have h1-h6 tags out of order if they emphasize correctly?

Tags: html

If I have a list of blog posts that are numbered h1-h3 but then have a header for all the posts with an h6 tag is this considered o-k practice? The emphasis is on the blog posts and not the ' recent posts' header . If not what is a better practice?

```
<h6> Recent posts </h6>
<h1> Why sports cars are cool!</h1>
<p> blah blah </p>   
<h2> Why trucks are cool!</h2>
<p> blah blah </p>
<h2> Why bikes are cool!</h2>
<p> blah blah </p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using headings correctly, and styles to achieve the aesthetics you require.

Comment: You do realize that this question wasn't about styling but about order? There are indeed three things to look for: styling/size, order of importance, and order of appearance. The first one isn't part of the qeustion at all ;)

Comment: Using a `h6` as a heading for something that contains `h1` and `h2` headings is grossly illogical, given the intended structural meaning of heading elements in HTML. As a whole, however, the question is mostly about interpretations of specifications, hence opinions – and the question is really rather undefined unless you specify which specifications (HTML versions) you regard as relevant.

Comment: If its illogical then what is the alternative if I want a heading but don't want it emphasized as h1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say order of appearance isn't important, just the level of importance is. As long as you got a `<h5>` somewhere, and as long as that one is more important then your `<h6>`, it's fine.

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5) states:

> There are six levels of headings in HTML with H1 as the **most important** and H6 as the **least**.

*(emphasis are mine)*

So: Order of importance is indeed what's important, not order of appearance (and neither size). Importance is their semantic meaning, so honor that one.

Actually, the hard part is not to figure out the semantics, but to determine how important each heading really is. I use to make tables of content of my webpages, properly strcuturing all `<h?>` contents as sub-headings of the last level - if it makes sense to see the data ordered like that, headings are used correctly.